# how to skip indexing document if such document exist?

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch

I use Spark to write lots of data into Elasticsearch. But some(sometimes most) of them are duplicated documents which have the same id in this context. Since writing data into ES takes much time, I want to know that how to skip indexing if the document's id is already existed in ES?

like:

```
if doc.id in ES:
    continue
else 
   doc.index(ES)
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how connection with spark works but in es you can set[operation type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html#operation-type).

```
PUT twitter/tweet/1?op_type=create
{
    "user" : "kimchy",
    "post_date" : "2009-11-15T14:12:12",
    "message" : "trying out Elasticsearch"
}
```

But the only problem

```
When create is used, the index operation will fail if a document by that id already exists in the index.
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the "only problem" is really a big problem for me. Do you know any method to suppress the exception?

Comment: @Mazz I would look to way how to suppress error on the client since ES will just return specific json body.